Store very large files in mysql db
My implementation is laravel, but this could generally apply to php/mysql.
I have a large file, generally about 500MB that I want to store in the database. If it helps, the file itself is a zip of pdfs.
The code is straightforward:
    $this->recordRequest->update([
      'data' => file_get_contents($file),
    ]);

The error I get is that I've run out of memory. Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 37456160 bytes).
What I'm looking for is something along these lines:

A method to stream data from php to mysql
A method to chunk the data for storage

Similarly, I'd need a way to present the data to the user, ideally by streaming the data from mysql. I haven't tried it, but maybe I could use repeated SUBSTRING() calls on the blob.
Non-starters

I realize that I could store the file in the filesystem or on S3 or somewhere else, but for now, I need to store it in the DB.
I can't increase the allowed memory size. My max_packet is about 15 MB, I can't change that either.


Out of curiosity, why do you need to store such files in a database?

The file system is local to this particular web server. The download request may go to another web server which does not share the same filesystem. My initial plan was to put the file on SharePoint, but it contains protected health information, and our Sharepoint instance is not HIPAA compliant.

Code example here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php

Though AFAIK Laravel doesn't support mysqli, and I don't know that PDO supports an equivalent method to send long data in parts. You may have to do some custom code to use mysqli to connect directly, not using Laravel-provided framework methods.

Split the zip file into several small files (because of max_allowed_packet) and load them into the database with LOAD_FILE(file_name).

One way to do this is to create a chuck of data by files you will need 2 table one for the file and other for the file chunk data:
Models:

File [id, name]
File Data [id, file_id, chunk_data]

Now you can create a relationship between the models:
class File extends Model {

 public function fileData () {
   return $this->many(FileData:class);
 }
}

Create a new file and store the information by chunk:
$fileModel = new File(basename($file));

$handle = fopen($file, 'rb'); // Open the file in binary mode for reading
if ($handle === false) {
    // Handle error opening the file
}

while (!feof($handle)) {
    $chunk = fread($handle, 4096); // Read 4KB chunk from the file
    // Process the chunk as needed
    // For example, you can write the chunk to another file, update the database, etc.
   $file->fileData([
'chunk_data' => $chunk
])->save();
}

fclose($handle); // Close the file handle

Now if you want to read the file data you can do it and restore to a file again by:
// Assume $file is the model instance representing the file stored in the database
$file = File::find($id); // Assuming $id is the ID of the file you want to read

// Open a new file for writing
$destinationPath = storage_path('app/'); // Destination directory for the new file
$fileName = $file->name; // Assume 'name' is the column containing the file name
$destinationFile = $destinationPath . $fileName;
$handle = fopen($destinationFile, 'wb'); // Open the file in binary mode for writing

if ($handle === false) {
    // Handle error opening the file
}

// Iterate over the collection of chunks and write each chunk to the destination file
foreach ($file->fileData as $chunk) {
    fwrite($handle, $chunk->chunk_data);
}

fclose($handle); // Close the file handle

echo "File has been written to: " . $destinationFile;

